# How to improve the detection of Probabilistic Hough Line Transform?

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing

I'm trying to detect a clock hand in a video of an analogue display and extract the value it points to. I'm using Python with OpenCV for this.

What I essentially do is:

1. I'm using a Gaussian Blur to lower the noise in the current image.
2. I use Canny Edge Detection to filter the edges
3. I apply the probabilistic Hough Line Transform

The Code for it:

```
def detect_clock_hand(img, center):
    # Convert to gray
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

    # Apply gaussian blur
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (11, 11), 0, 0)

    # Apply sobel edge detection
    edges = cv2.Canny(blur, 30, 40)

    # Apply HoughTransform
    lines = cv2.HoughLinesP(edges, 10, np.pi / 180, 5, 15, 50)

    #Filter lines in a given radius
    filtered_edges = util.filter_edges(lines, center)
```

I played a lot with the parameters to improve the results. The current status looks like this:

1. Canny
   [image: Canny]

2. Hough
   [image: HoughLineTransformP]

As you can see, the result just marks a part of the clockhand. And that part isn't even a 'good' part from what I can tell from the Canny Edge Detection. I'm wondering if I use the Hough Line Transform wrong or the Edge Detection actually isn't as good as I think it is. Since I'm new to Image Processing, I'd be grateful for any advice.

Comment: hi, I don't think that the right place to ask this, we're not vision specialist here. Maybe if you can make the white lines bolder they would overstep each other and the detection will work better ?

Comment: You obviously know more about this than I do, but I've a couple of questions:  a) it appears the camera isn't entirely orthogonal to the gauge - would it help to move the camera? b) can you  physically mask out the rest of the image?  Put a piece of cardboard just in front of the lens so you've got less noise. c) What about comparing successive frames?  If the only thing moving is the clockhand, you might be able to make some useful inferences.  Good luck on this - it sounds like fun.

Comment: [Signal Processing](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/) might be a good place to ask this question.

Comment: That looks like a pressure gauge - could you possibly replace it (or add another inline) that has an output port?  Solving the problem with hardware feels like cheating, but it might be the cheapest/easiest solution.

Comment: @Walfrat, didn't think of that. But the thickness doesn't really have an effect on the detection here. Maybe it is worth taking that into account, but as for now, I'll avoid it, since I don't know how much time it will consume.

Comment: @DanPichelman, a) you are right. Though it isn't guaranteed that the camera will be orthogonal or centered. I think about taking care of that in some preprocessing though (through some initial configuration by the user). b) That is not possible c) I thought about doing that to refine the edge detection.

Solving it with hardware is out of question, because of several reason, that I don't want to specify.
Thanks for the link. I'll ask there to and maybe refer to this place.

Comment: Did you intend to use the Hough line transform or circle transform?